# Why does RDS have warm-up

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a t3.micro postgresql (storage autoscaling) instance on AWS RDS. If I wait for something like 30 minutes after making an initial query and make the same query again, it takes up to 10 seconds longer. Why does RDS have an "warm-up" when I pay for it to run 24/7?

edit: it is not aurora serverless

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no warm-up in RDS (unless you're using Aurora). The `t3` instance class has burstable performance, which could be part of the explanation here. It's also possible you're seeing some sort of query/plan caching expire.

Comment: RDS is indeed always on and does not have any kind of systemic warm up, so we need to seek another explanation @BjørnRivallAndersen2018v. Possibly the most significant question you can answer next is whether anything else is happening on that server between your two test queries.  Are other queries being run, or backups being taken, etc., in the interim?

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour suggests that it’s [**Aurora Serverless** PostgreSQL database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html).

Standard RDS or Aurora doesn’t have warm-up time, while Serverless Aurora does exactly those 10s to 15s for a cold start.

Post a screenshot of your RDS settings if you’re 100% sure it’s not Serverless and you still experience this warm up time.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Br0rn said it's a t3.micro server, so I guess it's not serverless. Serverless appear to be billed using capacity units. I wonder if data had been cached before the first query, but evicted before the second query as RAM was needed.

Comment: @Tim TBH the years on StackExchange taught me that people not always get their facts right ;)

Comment: Fair call :) But if someone specifies a server size it's probably not serverless :)